# flurry - How to view churn count/rate?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

On the flurry dashboard, we can see under Usage > User Retention, the number of retained users.  I'm wondering how about the churn count/rate.  How do we view the number of users who stopped using the application after some time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea if you monitor Usage>Active Users in your application. This would give you with information on how many unique users are actively using your app on a daily/weekly/monthly basis.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)